# Shopify get latest single review of a product

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I need to fetch a single latest review given by user and display in a box on product detail page.

I have searched in google for shopify script and app but couldn't find any solution for this. If anybody have done this type of task then please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Shopify has a review App. When you use it in a shop, you can display reviews. Since you control the placement of the reviews, you are in a position to also inspect the reviews from DOM perspective and decide the latest, and what the markup looks like.

Since you know the markup, and you have access to the Shop, you can scrape the latest review using any screen scraper you want to use. With that, you can easily have each products newest review sent back to the App you installed in the shop. Using an App Proxy, you can do a callback asking for the details of the latest review, if any exist, for re-display any way you want.

Sure that is convoluted and weird, but you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify have its own review app any one can leave review on your products.
You just need to install and configure that app.
I can help you to setup review app it is minutes change

Comment: I know very well about the product review app but my requirement is different. I need to fetch a single latest review of a product.

Comment: you to do with jquery ajax and shopify api for that review app

Comment: Can you provide me any script or reference url for this.